# How to get variable from javascript to php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I want to get a variable from the code value:

```
/* Link Skor */
Memory.prototype.cekSkor = function(){
    window.location = "./skor/index.php?value=" + this.numMoves;
}

Memory.prototype._winGame = function() {
    var self = this;
    if (this.options.onGameEnd() === false) {
        this._clearGame();
        this.gameMessages.innerHTML = 
            '<h2 class="mg__onend--heading">Keren!</h2>\
            <p class="mg__onend--message">Kamu memenangkan game ini dalam ' + this.numMoves + ' gerakan.</p>\
            <button id="mg__onend--restart" class="mg__button">Ingin Bermain Lagi?</button>\
            <button id="mg__onend--skor" class="mg__button">Cek Skor?</button>';
        this.game.appendChild(this.gameMessages);
        document.getElementById("mg__onend--restart").addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
            self.resetGame();
        });
        document.getElementById("mg__onend--skor").addEventListener( "click", function(e) {
            self.skor();
        });
    } else {
        // run callback
        this.options.onGameEnd();
    }
}
```

I want get the ( this.numMoves ) to another file is index.php

```
<?php
        $skornya = $_GET['value'];
        echo $skornya;
?>
```

when i run the web. i get error
The value= not read

[image]

What need i do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no way. =). In PHP just can receive $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, or $data = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );

If you want variable in javascript can be use in PHP. you must post it to server using with XMLHttpRequest in Javascript, ajax in jQuery. hope this help you

Comment: emmm sorry i wrong question i have function for the click in button that

/* Link Skor */
  Memory.prototype.cekSkor = function(){
  window.location = "./skor/index.php?value=" + this.numMoves;
  }

Comment: if you use this, in PHP you just use $_GET["value"], everthing is resolve =)

Comment: you can check with echo $_GET["value"]

Answer (score 0):

The browser then interprets the text as HTML and JavaScript. If you want to get data from JavaScript to PHP then you need to make a new HTTP request and run a new (or the same) PHP script. You can make an HTTP request from JavaScript by using a form or Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on the client side while php runs on server side and the response of processed php server is sent to the client. 
So if you want to send a variable from javascript to php it is same as sending data from client to the server.
So, you can do the following:

In Javascript:

```
var toSend = "hello" //variable to send.
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: url,
 data: toSend,
 success: success,
 dataType: dataType
});
```

In  PHP use $_POST method for reading the data.